# Making a API for currentUser in MEAN

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, angular-services

I am using JWT for authenticating a user. I have wrote some functions for getting the current user which is working fine but I need to make that functions as API so that, It can be called from anywhere.

**token-service.service.ts**

```
  currentUser(): { _id: string; username: string; role: string; email: string } {
    return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.authToken()).user;
  }

  authToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  setToken(token) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  clearToken() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
 get currentUser(): { _id: string; username: string; role: string; email: string } {
    return this.tokenService.currentUser();
  }

  get loggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.tokenService.loggedIn();
  }
```

I want to make currentUser As a API GET method. Because It has to be called from another machine.

Comment: *currentUser As a API GET method* & *called from another machine.*..... Can you explain further what do mean by this two term?

Comment: Your code won't work on the backend as it is, as you're using `localStorage` which is only available in the browser. Are you asking for help porting your code across to Node.js? Please be more specific about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: yeah i need to write a API code for currentUser method